# SSH demon not installed in linux embedded device

Tags: linux, upgrade, embedded, sshd

I have an embedded device which runs linux(arm). I am trying to update the executable through **ethernet** using **scp** command. But I got to know that *sshd* is not running in the device . I need to install the ssh library in device. But I have only access to a serial port (debug) and ethernet.I have compiled ssh library using cross compiler toolchain but how can i install this on my device?

Do I need to configure rfs again ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218578/install-ssh-server-on-embedded-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the sshd to the embedded device with tftp. For e.g. at `/usr/bin/sshd` and execute it. Then try connecting to the embedded device.

Comment: How to copy that through ethernet or serial??

Comment: Do u have Tftp cluent on the board?

Comment: Yep It is there. :)

Comment: Then you know how to copy. Setup Tftp server on your mavhine and get it on the embedded board

Comment: yeah i got it .ty